# Expo app.config.js googleServicesFile for different build variants

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to be able to differentiate between build variants on my Expo App.

At the moment I have my expo config in my app.config.js like so

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let AndroidGoogleServicesFile = './google-services-dev.json';

if (Constants.manifest.releaseChannel === 'staging') {
  AndroidGoogleServicesFile = './google-services-staging.json';
}
if (Constants.manifest.releaseChannel === 'release') {
  AndroidGoogleServicesFile = './google-services.json';
}
...
{
...
android: {
  adaptiveIcon: {
    foregroundImage: './assets/images/adaptive-icon.png',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  package: 'com.companyname.App',
  googleServicesFile: AndroidGoogleServicesFile,
},
...
```

AS you can see i want to be able to configure my `googleServicesFile` based on `releaseChannel` or build variant but this doesn't seem possible at the moment? I am using EAS to build aswell and i'm not sure i can configure it in my `eas.json` either...

Comment: I'm having same issue, have you found a way to do this?

Comment: I ended up running a node task before each build (and slimmed it down by putting the scripts in my package JSON. The node process takes my flavor as an argument and then populates the relevant parts of the eas configuration and expo.json I'll try dig out some code for you

Comment: @Tj3n https://gist.github.com/ZEAL-MATCH-LTD/754d451d7de338080eddfffe43110edf

Comment: @FrancisLeigh did you find any other fix to this problem?

Comment: @DarkSide77 not yet, do you have a more elegant solution?

Comment: hey @FrancisLeigh I found I better way to do this I inspired from your question you can check it here's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74866313/13546478