# expo: how to load different google-services-json based on release channel expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a different google-service.json file for every releaseChannel (a file for prod, stage, QA, and dev)

for more details I want to implement push notifications but in a different environment.
cuz I don't want to send a test notification in the QA and the notification sent to the prod users!

this is the android config in `app.json`

```
"android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/adaptive-icon.png"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
      ],
      "package": "com.beyondbelievers.awal",
      "versionCode": 1
    },Ï
```

is there any way I can load the different files with every environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this answer inspired from an old question you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018036/expo-app-config-js-googleservicesfile-for-different-build-variants)
after I searched the whole internet I found a way but using `app.config.js`

I will try to explain how I archive my goal in the following steps:

- convert `app.json` to `app.config.js`: [here's expo docs explain how to migrate from `app.json`](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/).
- then in my `eas.json` I added the following line to all profiles `"APP_VARIANT": "qa"`:

```
{
    "qa": {
      ...
      "releaseChannel": "qa",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "qa"
      }
      ...
    },
    "stage": {
      ...
      "releaseChannel": "stage",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "stage"
      }
      ...
    },
    "prod": {
      ...
      "releaseChannel": "prod",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "prod"
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

the `"APP_VARIANT"` variable contains the type of env and based on it I can later check which file to us.

- now back to the `app.config.js` add the following lines:

```
    // this will return the value of APP_VARIANT defined in eas.json
    const APP_RELEASE_CHANNEL = process.env.APP_VARIANT;
    
    // define the AndroidGoogleServicesFile variable to use instead of the normal string and assign a default value to it
    let AndroidGoogleServicesFile = "./google-services-dev.json";
    
    
    // now check the value of the APP_VARIANT and based on it assign the path of the google-services you wanna use
        if (APP_RELEASE_CHANNEL === "qa") {
          AndroidGoogleServicesFile = "./google-services-qa.json";
        } else if (APP_RELEASE_CHANNEL === "stage") {
          AndroidGoogleServicesFile = "./google-services-stage.json";
        } else if (APP_RELEASE_CHANNEL === "prod") {
          AndroidGoogleServicesFile = "./google-services-prod.json";
        }
```

- now you know which file you need to use one step left is to assign that file so your app can use it

```
android: {
    ...
    googleServicesFile: AndroidGoogleServicesFile,
    ...
  },
```

this is how I solve my problem I hope this solves your problem too.

If you didn't understand something I welcomed to explain in more details

Comment: could you please explain about the app package name (and sha codes)? because we cannot add the same package name inside two firebase apps, how to handle this programatically with expo?